# Updating edge key values in Networkx multi-graph

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I'm using Networkx to create an undirected multi-graph and I am removing edges from it. Upon creationg I am adding unique keys to these edges: `G.add_edge(u,v,key=i, ... )`. So, say I have 3 edges between nodes `u` and `v` with keys 0,1,2 and I remove the edge with key value 1 `G.remove_edge(u,v,key=1)`. Is there a way to update the remaining edges with keys=0,2 to have keys 0,1 without removing and adding edges from the graph?

I tried this:

```
e_dict = dict(G[0][1])
for i, key in enumerate(list(e_dict.keys())):
    e_dict[i] = e_dict.pop(key)
G[0][1] = e_dict
```

Which produces the right dictionary but `G[0][1]` isn't a dictionary but an AdjacencyView object so the assignment does not work. Does anyone know a way this can be done? I'm a bit confused by the documentation. Thanks!